# A - hover effect having troubles

Tags: html, css

I am making a website with a custom menu bar, but when you haver over just the menu, the text does not change. I know this is because of the link, but how do I make it to where the text changes color when an area is hovered over (instead of the link)?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: you can't do html code on this site

Comment: Offcourse you can

Comment: *"A hover effect having troubles"* - I kinda expected some humorous short story. Anyway, as others have mentioned, please edit your post to include a Stack Snippet with your (relevant) HTML/CSS, so we can actually see what's going on. You might want to read up on [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but your question seems vague, at least for me :)

You mean something like this:

```css
.test {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.test a {
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.test:hover {
  background:#fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.test:hover a {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class = "test">
    <a href="#">Test Link</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

You can run the code above.